# How to add line breaks in a string when a character limit is reached without breaking the words?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

If I have this var:

```
var string = 'My life is beautiful 1. My life is beautiful 2. My life is beautiful 3.'
```

And I want to add a 23 character limit per line. 
What should I do to get this/ to add line breaks when the character limit is reached

```
My life is beautiful 1.
My life is beautiful 2.
My life is beautiful 3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression like this to capture 23 characters at a time and create an array of strings. Finally join them with `\n`, like this

```js
var string = 'My life is beautiful 1.My life is beautiful 2.My life is beautiful 3.';
console.log(string.match(/.{23}/g).join('\n'));
```